# How to eval memory group in a variable using perl?

Tags: regex, perl, eval, regex-group

In a perl script, I want to evaluate memory group special variable in a string variable :

```
my $string="3-4";
my $cal='first is $1;second is $2';
my $regex='^(.)-(.)$';

if($string=~ $regex){
    print $cal;
        #print "first is $1;second is $2";
}
```

I want to print : "first is 3;second is 4" (like in second print).

In my sample, there is only 2 special variable but the number of special char cannot be determined in advance because `$cal` and `$regex` are stored in a database.

How can I evaluate the string `$cal` (like with eval in php ) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print eval "\"$cal\"","\n";
```

The outer dblquotes are for eval "", the inner escaped quotes are for interpolation inside `print "$1 $2","\n";`

or, you can combine the print segments like this `print eval "\"$cal\n\"";`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to define a pattern into which your matches will be inserted? You could use [printf](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) for that, e.g.

```
my $string="3-4";
my $cal="%s %s\n";
if($string=~ '^(.)-(.)$'){
    printf($cal, $1, $2);
}
```

If you simply want to join all matches together, and you don't know how many there might be, try something like this

```
my @matches=$string=~ '^(.)-(.)$';
if (scalar(@matches))
{
    print join(' ',@matches);
}
```

Comment: I thought that was your question - how to make the first print do what the second one does. I've edited my answer to make it clearer how it relates to your original anyway - the 'pattern' you want the output to follow is in $cal

Comment: I understand your answer but i can't know in advance how many special variable may be use in $cal

Comment: Suggest you edit the question then - that aspect is not clear (everything about your sample indicates just two elements in your pattern)

Comment: Sorry Paul, my question was not clear. Thank you for your answers.